# Excel - sumifs - condition when cell contains string

Tags: sum, cell, excel-formula

I need little help with excel. I use SUMIF func. Here is my formula.

```
=SUMIFS(J:J;B:B;O4;G:G;"=ISTEXT(Intercall)")
```

I would like make a sum from values in **J** column, where:

- values in column B are same as **O4**
- and where values in **column G contain specific string**

for example value in column G is Intercall - Taiwan -> thi value contains string Intercall

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but maybe this will help.

SUMIFS accepts wildcards in criteria. So you can use:

```
=SUMIFS(J:J;B:B;O4;G:G;="*Intercall*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to make a [multiple criteria SUMIF](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/sum-if.htm).

In your case, the formula could look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J1:J22)*(B1:B22=$O$4)*(G1:G22="Intercall"))
```

I'm not sure i understood properly your last point (is the string the same for every cell?)

Comment: No condition contain string means that: